# Check for empty GUID in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I check if an argument in a stored procedure is an empty GUID or not?

Answer (score 141):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

That should return your empty guid.

... or even shorter, saving one cast:

```
SELECT CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

So to check for that, you would do

```
IF @GuidParam = CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
BEGIN
   --Guid is empty
END
```

Comment: You could use this alternate syntax to get an empty guid CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

Comment: @Robert +1 for using 0x0 rather than 2 casts.

Comment: what has better performance this one or checking "If @Param = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' ?"

Comment: @JoãoAntunes - like most things it's usually more important what's more readable and less error prone, even if there is some speed difference. Personally I like the `0x0` approach because you're not left wondering if there's the right number of `0`s and `-`s. Performance-wise it's pretty hard to measure because they're both so fast, but in my naive measurement they're indistinguishable, each taking about 1 microsecond i.e. you can do about 1,000,000 casts per second.

Answer (score 21):

Since the empty guid never changes, the other obvious way is to simply use `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` rather than calculating it.

```
If @Param = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
...
```

Or, if in an procedure, you can set a parameter to act as a constant:

```
Declare @EmptyGuid uniqueidentifier
Set @EmptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Or you could create a scalar user-defined function which simply returns the above constant value (or recalculates it as in Meiscooldude solution).

Comment: StaticCodeAnalysis error : SR0014 : Data loss might occur when casting from ASCII String(36) to UniqueIdentifier.

Comment: @user2323308 - That's a false positive. We are setting the value to a constant. There's no room for data loss.

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 0x0
DECLARE @NonEmpty UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
IF @EmptyGuid = 0x0 PRINT 'Empty'
IF @NonEmpty = 0x0 PRINT 'Empty' ELSE PRINT 'NonEmpty'
```

Will print

Empty

NonEmpty

Comment: This is the correct answer for newer versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can make Empty Guid like this:

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @EmptyGuid = (SELECT CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))

-- Single result is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SELECT @EmptyGuid
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DECLARE @param UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
--DECLARE @param UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

IF (CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 0x00)) = @param
    PRINT 'Empty';
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not Empty';
```

Answer (score -7):

```
DECLARE @SupplierDataHubId  uniqueidentifier=null

 set @SupplierDataHubId=(select HubId from dbo.tblSupplierData where fldUpc='603259049389' OR   fldEan='6032590493895555')
if (@SupplierDataHubId is not null)
 begin                 
 print('yes');
end

else 
print 'no'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.