# How to check for empty or null Guid in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to check for null or empty GUID in stored procedure. I have used the below code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGuid]
    @buildingID XML,
AS
    DECLARE @fetchedBuildValue uniqueidentifier 
    SET @fetchedBuildValue = (SELECT data.item.value('./@ID', 'uniqueidentifier') AS PId
                              FROM @buildingID.nodes('/items/item') data(item));

    SELECT
        DemoUser.[ID],
        DemoUser.[Suffix],
        DemoUser.[BusinessPhoneNumber]
    INNER JOIN 
        Relationship AS T_U ON T_U.Target = DemoUser.ID 
                            AND T_U.TargetType = 0 
                            AND T_U.SourceType = 6
    INNER JOIN 
        DemoTenant ON T_U.Source = DemoTenant.ID
    WHERE
        (@firstname IS NULL OR DemoUser.FirstName LIKE '%' + @firstname + '%')
        AND ((@fetchedBuildValue = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'  
              AND Building.State = @state 
              AND Building.City = @city)
             OR 
             (@fetchedBuildValue != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
              AND Building.ID = @fetchedBuildValue))
```

The above stored procedure is not checking for empty guid. The guid that I am passing from code is in a xml as below:

```
<items><item ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" /></items>
```

However, if a valid guid is passed, it is working fine.

How can I add an empty check here so that when the guid is empty, my state and city where clause work instead of the guild column

Comment: I am not getting any error, it just that the SP is not returning the result. I am getting count as 0. However, when I manually run it, I am getting the desired result

Comment: when the sp does not returns the result, what is than the value in the variable fetchedBuildValue. Have you checked that in debug or by outputting or any other method ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for empty GUID in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092999/check-for-empty-guid-in-sql)